# McMaster-Carr's 'scrolling box' layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

McMaster-Carr, a few years back, completely redesigned their website and they now have these very cool '[scrolling box](http://www.mcmaster.com/#nylon-gears/=g1p46z)' sections for each product. I've been trying to duplicate that same effect only using css and html, but have had no luck so far.

Some key things I cannot accomplish using only html + css:

- hidden scrollbars with the ability to still scroll
- section headers that stop when scrolled to the top of a containing div

I've tried looking through their source code but I really want to start from scratch and recreate the effect, hopefully finding a much simpler way to recreate it.

If anyone has seen anything like this before or knows how to go about creating this type of layout, please help.

Here's a link to a page on the McMaster-Carr website that demonstrates that scrolling box layout:

http://www.mcmaster.com/#nylon-gears/=g1p46z

Comment: Are you referring to how the product sidebars will follow the scrollbar when you scroll past the specific product?

Comment: I'm only looking at the sections that have a small header ( 48 Pitch, 32 Pitch, etc. ) and their different measurements + prices - I'm trying to recreate the effect where the header hits the top of the div and stops, the content under that header scrolls within the containing div, and once the section has scrolled all of the way down, both the header and content continue up for the next section. Does that make sense?

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/examples/PersistantHeaders/

Comment: this only works if the header stops at the top of a window - not within a containing div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The technique j08691 [linked](http://css-tricks.com/examples/PersistantHeaders/) to is the common way to do it - you'll have to use a bit of JS to find out where how much the site is scrolled. If you look at the source of the persistent header example, there is a line like

```
scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop()
```

simply replace this by the top position of your parent div (assuming it is, like in McMaster, fixed on the site)

```
scrollTop = $("div.MyParentDiv").position().top
```

Comment: how can i make that work with this though? `code` $('#all_posts h2').each(function(i,e){     
    var posT = $(this).offset().top;
    $(this).data('posT', posT);
});  

var srcTop = 0;   
var t = '';

$('#all_posts').scroll(function(){
  
  scrTop = $(this).scrollTop();
 
  $('#all_posts h2').each(function(i,e){  
     if( scrTop > $(this).data('posT') ){
         $('#titles').show().html($(this).html()) ;
     }
    else if(scrTop <= 0){
          $('#titles').hide().html('');
    }   
  });
}); `code`