# stacking divs when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, z-index

I want to format the posts on a blog to have stacking 'title divs' when the user scrolls down the page. The only way for me to explain this was to make a little [demo](http://scrollstack.tumblr.com) by cheating and using z-index all over the place to simulate how it's supposed to look.

I want to recreate this effect but make it applicable to posts on a blog. Is this possible?

EDIT: Trying to find a way to create this effect using javascript.

Here's the current css:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

h2, h3, p {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#container {
    position: relative;
    width: 360px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

#header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    width: 360px;
    height: 60px;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 10;
}

#right_column {
    width: 360px;
    margin: 60px 0px 0px 0px;
}

    #right_column .first_title {
        position: relative;
        margin: 0px;
        font-size:32px;
        line-height: 30px;
        z-index: 9;
        background: #fff;
    }

    #right_column .first_fixed {
        position: fixed;
        top: 60px;
        z-index:6;
        width: 360px;
        background: #eee;
        border-top: #999 1px solid;
    }

    #right_column .first {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 5;
        background: #fff;
    }

    #right_column .second_title {
        position: relative;
        margin: 0px;
        font-size:32px;
        line-height: 30px;
        z-index: 5;
        background: #fff;
    }

    #right_column .second_fixed {
        width: 360px;
        position: fixed;
        top: 80px;
        z-index: 3;
        border-top: #999 1px solid;
        background: #eee;
    }

    #right-column .second {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 2;
    }
```

Here's the markup:

```
    <h2 class="first_title">This is the article title.</h2>
        <h3 class="first_fixed">This is the article title.</h3>
                 <p class="first">This is some text.</p>
    <h2 class="second_title">This is the article title.</h2>
        <h3 class="second_fixed">This is the article title.</h3>
                <p class="second">This is some text.</p>
```

Comment: Why don't you just "cheat" on your blog too and use z-index all over the place?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here - you'd like to create this effect without using `z-index`? It seems you've already got a solution applicable to posts on a blog.

Comment: When somebody posts on a blog, they aren't going to want to increase the index value of each consecutive post every time.

Comment: Then you need to provide a more in-depth description of what you are looking for. Do you want a javascript solution? A backend solution? Have you tried *anything* you can show us?

Comment: The answer is "it's definitely possible" but there are so many possible solutions, your question is not really answerable in it's current form.

Comment: preferably a javascript solution - my apologies on not being specific about that.

Comment: No need to increase the z-index value of each blog post when you can set it to the unique id of each database row. (assuming you're going to be using a backend) If you aren't using a backend, just write a javascript function that runs through all of the blog posts and sets the z-index equivalent to a counter that just increases after each blog post.

Comment: If the problem is just consecutive numbering of z-indexes, just use javascript. Loop through the posts and just apply an increasing integer to the z-index styles. Without posting actual code people can hack at though, you're not likely to get a good answer (if you get an answer at all). Maybe separate out the important/essential parts of your demo and add them to your question?

Comment: Like this: http://css-tricks.com/examples/PersistantHeaders/?

Comment: how does mcmaster-carr pull it off on their site? http://www.mcmaster.com/#nylon-gears/=g1p46z

Comment: I've seen the persistent headers example before... it only works if you're fixing the headers at the top of the browser window, not within a containing div

Comment: Please don't submit duplicate questions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9084369/mcmaster-carrs-scrolling-box-layout#comment11406557_9084369

Comment: Just to get you an idea: http://jsbin.com/aholuv/edit#javascript,html,live - And BTW, by a end-user perspective, let's say you have 10 posts... you'll end up having a mess of titles in the top. The way I used shows the 'currently reading' one.

Comment: how ballin' of you to help me with, this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are asking for .. I suppose you are trying to have an alternative to the one you already found. In this case you might want to have a look at the jQuery waypoints plugin in this [example](http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/sticky-elements/) .. you define markers which trigger events when you scroll the page.
Here its [main page](http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/)